# Form model bypasses validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a user model `MyProject\SecurityBundle\Entity\User` with validation constraints. For my registration, I created `MyProject\SecurityBundle\Form\Model\Registration`:

```
namespace MyProject\SecurityBundle\Form\Model;

use MyProject\SecurityBundle\Entity\User;

class Registration
{
    private $user;

    private $termsAccepted;

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setTermsAccepted($termsAccepted)
    {
        $this->termsAccepted = (boolean)$termsAccepted;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTermsAccepted()
    {
        return $this->termsAccepted;
    }
}
```

with validation:

```
MyProject\SecurityBundle\Form\Model\Registration:
    properties:
        user:
            - Type: { type: MyProject\SecurityBundle\Entity\User }
        termsAccepted:
            - NotBlank: ~
    getters:
        termsAccepted:
            - "True": ~
```

This validation works, but the validation for the user entity is bypassed by this. Is there a way I can tunnel the validation into my registration model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had searched in the **right** place, I would have found http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Valid.html this in the documentation and with it the solution:

```
MyProject\SecurityBundle\Form\Model\Registration:
    properties:
        user:
            - Type: { type: MyProject\SecurityBundle\Entity\User }
            - Valid: ~
```